# Pinch Zoom in amcharts 5

Tags: reactjs, charts, amcharts, amcharts5

I'm coding an XY chart using amcharts 5 library in react and I want to enable the pinch zoom. I tried with the parameters pinchZoomX pinchZoomY as specified in this link https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/reference/ixychartsettings/#pinchZoomX_property

Here the code:

```
const chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
    panX: true,
    panY: true,
    wheelY: 'zoomXY',
    pinchZoomX: 'true',
    pinchZoomY: 'true',
    }));
```

but the zoom do not work. I didn't find any other information about pinch zoom with amcharts. Can someone  help me please? What shall I do to enable the pinch zoom? Shall I specify other parameters to enable the mobile gesture in amcharts?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

The link that you shared of amcharts of [PinchZoom](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/zoom-and-pan/#Pinch_zoom) is still is in progress to use it. This is a bit [example](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/column-with-rotated-series/#code) as it seems to work for you.

Here you can do like this:

```
const chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
    panX: true,
    panY: true,
    wheelX: "panX",
    wheelY: "zoomX",
    pinchZoomX: true,
}));
```

I hope this helps you.